# Friction along a ladder

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

[image]

Here in the picture,the free body diagram of the ladder has been drawn, we can see that friction acts at point $A$ which is fine,but my question is why isn't any frictional force shown along point $B$?I mean if the ladder is to move down,then shouldn't there be a frictional force to oppose that action?

Comment: What does your problem statement say?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right!! There is friction on point $B$ and it also contributes to hold down the ladder at its point. And as you know that friction depends upon the normal force $N$ ($N_2$ in your case).
Thus $$F_{s1} \leq N_1 \cdot \mu_{se}$$$$F_{s2} \leq N_2 \cdot \mu_{se}$$
And in case of the ladder is slipping : $$F_{k2} = N_2 \cdot \mu_{k2}$$ $$F_{k1} = N_1 \cdot \mu_{k1}$$

Comment: The coefficient of static friction gives only the maximum allowed friction and only applies in this case if the ladder is about to slip.

Comment: I think now it is correct. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There might be friction at the upper end, but that would change the lower friction and both normal forces. To solve the problem, you would need to be given one of the forces.  In this case you are to assume that the upper friction is zero.